# Finding the number assigned to monitors (i.e., system with more than one monitor connected) by ubuntu using gsettings command

Tags: ubuntu, display, monitor, gnome, multiple-monitors

On systems with more than one monitors ubuntu assigns numbers to each monitor to identify them. I would like to query the numbers assigned to the monitors along with the interface names. Example:
DP-1 : 1 HDMI-1 : 2 VGA : 3

[image]

Comment: Can this help - https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/gsettings-monitor-all-system-settings-change-4175677656/

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov thank you for the comment but this didnt help.